# How to retrieve SVN+SSH username in eclipse in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, ssh

I have checked-out one of the project from SVN (using SSH protocol) (been a long time).

I want to retrieve the SVN username that I had used when I checkout this project in **ECLIPSE**.

What I tried:

- Saw the properties of the project - no luck
- Saw the .eclipse folder for the settings/config - no luck

Is there any way I can see the username (if possible password) for the SVN project that I used to checkout in eclipse?

**Note:**

The SVN installed on my machine is Subclipse and I have never committed to this repository but checked-out the project.

Comment: Not enough infos for now: There are 2 eclipse svn plugins (subversive and subclipse) and the ssh connection might be done through an external ssh connection.

Comment: @Turbo Please see the updated revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion stores the relevant account data in your home directory.

For example on Windows 7 you will find a lot of files regarding Subversion in the directory

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion
```

On Linux it is `~/.subversion`

Look into the `auth` subdirectory.

Comment: can you also tell me one for Linux system?

Comment: well I don't find any username anywhere inside this folder.

Comment: I just deleted the above folder and it worked for me. NOT SURE WHY.

Answer (score 0):

In subclipse, I'd use `Team->Show History`. Then you have the username in the `Author` column. You just need to find one of your own commits.

Comment: Good point, what if I am the new person & had never committed to this project?

Comment: I am very sorry that was a mis-typo.